# Allowing function to accept various types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

***UPD** I realized this question is not precisely correct for I was trying to do something which is common for me from Erlang experience. As answer explains my functions should be narrowed down in type, not type "extended" to adopt them...*

---

*(this is a test project while trying to learn/assess Haskell)*
Here is a part of intended basic web-endpoint, returning either single entity (for request with id) or list of all (for request without id):

This naive code works:

```
doGet req resp =
    let path = map T.unpack (pathInfo req)
    in case path of
        ["molecule"] -> makeResponse resp doGetAllMolecules
        ["molecule", strId] -> makeResponse resp $ doGetMolecule strId

makeResponse resp f = do
    res <- f
    resp $ responseLBS status200 [] (LC8.pack $ (show res) ++ "\n")

doGetMolecule :: String -> IO (Maybe Db.Molecule)
doGetMolecule strId = Db.fetchMolecule (read strId :: Int)

doGetAllMolecules :: IO [Db.Molecule]
doGetAllMolecules = Db.fetchAllMolecules
```

Now I want it to return `status404` when entity is not found:

```
makeResponse resp f = do
    res <- f
    let s = case res of
                Nothing -> status404
                _ -> status200
    resp $ responseLBS s [] (LC8.pack $ (show res) ++ "\n")
```

this leads to error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[Db.Molecule]’ with ‘Maybe a0’
  Expected type: IO (Maybe a0)
    Actual type: IO [Db.Molecule]
• In the second argument of ‘makeResponse’, namely
    ‘doGetAllMolecules’
  In the expression: makeResponse resp doGetAllMolecules
  In a case alternative:
      ["molecule"] -> makeResponse resp doGetAllMolecules
```

So what is the way to "match on type" of the value, allowing it to be either Maybe or anything else?

Comment: Aren't you looking for `fmap`? Do you know how typeclasses work?

Comment: What about sum type, eg. `data MoleculeResult = SingleMolecule (Maybe Db.Molecule) | MultiMolecule [Db.Molecule]`? It is closest I can image to "match on type"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
doGetMolecule :: String -> IO (Maybe [Db.Molecule])
doGetMolecule strId = fmap (:[]) <$> Db.fetchMolecule (read strId :: Int)

doGetAllMolecules :: IO (Maybe [Db.Molecule])
doGetAllMolecules = Just <$> Db.fetchAllMolecules
```

Now they have the same type: both have a chance at returning a list of molecules, so `doGet` need only handle that one type.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I've just logged in to update the question as I also ended up this way. I realized that my question is not very correct, as I was trying to make Haskell working like Erlang (to which I've got used to certain extent) - and this is wrong... The other option as I understand, is to create "typeclass" (or should it be just type?) for response, so it can be either Maybe, or some value... and create different processing functions via "instances" (?) - but it don't sound right even if it could really work (I'm not sure)...